# flash table widget that can save as PDF

Tags: flash, pdf

I'm trying to render a HTML table of tabular data in Flash. Are there any widgets out there to do this?

Ideally I would also like to save the contents of the table as PDF.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

for rendering the table, you can try to port this [AS2 component](http://www.flash-db.com/FlashTable/) to AS3, although you still won't be having full support ... other than that, you can still write it on your own, based on [this flex component](http://code.google.com/p/flex-table/) or from scratch ...

to output a PDF, try [alive PDF](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/) ... very simple way to generate the PDF on the client side ... otherwise send the HTML to the server, and let the server use some HTML2PDF library ... there's many ... some good, some not so good ...

good luck then ... ;)

greetz

back2dos